# Simple refactoring for duplicated logic call

Tags: refactoring

I'm working on a unity c# project and refactoring some of my messy physics codes recently.

There's a simple logic I'd like to refactor in one of my monobehaviour's update () method :

```
if (collision box dirty)
    Check collision
move player using physics value
Check collision
```

In my game, Collision Box Size & center Position Changes very dynamically so that's why I need to check if collision box is dirty & do collision checking.

As you see I do same logic twice in a method, and I feel like it can be more simple(or clearer). Any little advice will be great help for a beginner programmer like me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should show us a sample of this code you are talking about.

Comment: Oh...Sorry, For now It's just a logic...maybe I had to ask about this after coding. Tell me if my question was not right, Then I'll delete this one.